# Find certain file type in c and save it

Tags: c, linux, find

I need to find files of a certain type (.bin) in a folder and then sort their content and rename the sorted files again. Any ideas on how to do this? This far i have only

```
system("find -03 -L /home/Desktop/Folder1 "*.bin");
```

and i have no idea what to do next. Please help !

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `system()` if you can. C lets you do all these things without having to call external programs.

Use the `opendir()`, `readdir()` and `closedir()` functions to get the names of all files in a directory. For every filename, check if it has the right extension, and if so add it to an array, You can use the `qsort()` function to sort the array. You can rename files using the `rename()` function.

If you need to do this recursively, then have a look at the `ftw()` and `nftw()` functions.

Comment: Thank you !! This really helped !

Comment: Even if you wanted to use an external program, you wouldn't use `system` for it. `popen` maybe.

Comment: The truth is i dont want to sort the files but their content and then save the sorted files in an array. Any ideas on this?

Comment: That's a different question.